# How do I resolve the compiler error: invalid use of void expression?

Tags: c

```
turtle(int fd,int sec1,int turtle_speed){

     signal(SIGUSR1,handle(fd,turtle_speed));

    struct timeval b;

    int flag=1,turtle_current_pos,turtle_previous_pos=0,sec2;

    turtle_current_pos=0;

    while(turtle_current_pos<100){

            sleep(2);

                gettimeofday(&b,NULL);

    sec2=b.tv_sec;

    //printf("%d\n",sec2);

    turtle_current_pos=(sec2-sec1)*turtle_speed;
    fflush(stdout);

    if((turtle_current_pos-turtle_previous_pos)>=1){
        turtle_previous_pos=turtle_current_pos;
        print('T',turtle_previous_pos);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a void expression in an invalid manner, you should only use the expression in a valid manner?  Seriously, if you don't say where the error is or give some context, it is very difficult for people to help you.

Comment: What is `handle()`? At the very least, indicate to us *which line of code* is causing the error.

Comment: It's the first line. See my answer.

Comment: See [SO 3433042](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433042/why-do-i-get-compiler-error-sigsur1-was-not-declared-in-this-scope) for more of the code.

Comment: I don't think that we should answer questions as badly posed like this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the first line. You have to pass a function pointer, while it looks like you're calling the function, which happens to have a void return type. It also looks like you want C to have closures - you're trying to pass arguments to the signal handler function. This is not possible. You'll need to store those values in global variables, and declare your signal handler with the correct prototype for a signal handler.